# Let $_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{R}[x]$ a vector space, show that $<f,g > = gr(fg)$ is not an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Probably this is a simple question but I have been stuck for a while because I don't find the counterexample. $gr(fg)$ denotes the graph of the function.

Comment: The graph of the function? It is does make sense to you? An inner product is a function that takes two vectors and return an scalar.

Comment: Sure! Thank you!